# Database Error: MySQL Error Number: 1064

Tags: php, mysql, sql, codeigniter

I can't for the life of me figure out what the issue here is, maybe another pair of eyes may help:

Here is the error message:

```
Error Number: 1064

You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '://www.amazon.com/Lemon-Recipes-Alkalizing-Addition-Delectable-ebook/dp/B00CZTCS' at line 1

INSERT INTO `books` (`asin`, `keyword_id`, `page_count`, `sales_rank`, `price`, `link`) VALUES (B00CZTCS9K, 1, 77, 96317, 2.25, http://www.amazon.com/Lemon-Recipes-Alkalizing-Addition-Delectable-ebook/dp/B00CZTCS9K%3FSubscriptionId%3DAKIAJPNAWJHXGB5IYXOA%26tag%3Dgenroad-21%26linkCode%3Dxm2%26camp%3D2025%26creative%3D165953%26creativeASIN%3DB00CZTCS9K)
```

Comment: you need to put string in single quotes `'http://www.a......'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As *M Khalid Junaid* mentioned you will need to wrap string in a single quote.
That means both `'B00CZTCS9K'` and the link `'http://....'` should be wrapped.

The rest look like decimals but, if any other value is a string(varchar) than wrap it also.

Answer (score 0):

Try this, Added `'` quotes for `asin and link` column values those are strings. String are need to be wrapped around quotes.

```
  INSERT INTO `books` (`asin`, `keyword_id`, `page_count`, `sales_rank`, `price`, `link`) 
  VALUES ('B00CZTCS9K', 1, 77, 96317, '2.25', 'http://www.amazon.com/Lemon-Recipes-Alkalizing-Addition-Delectable-ebook/dp/B00CZTCS9K%3FSubscriptionId%3DAKIAJPNAWJHXGB5IYXOA%26tag%3Dgenroad-21%26linkCode%3Dxm2%26camp%3D2025%26creative%3D165953%26creativeASIN%3DB00CZTCS9K')
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to put quotes around all strings, including URLs:

```
INSERT INTO `books` (`asin`, `keyword_id`, `page_count`, `sales_rank`, `price`, `link`) 
VALUES ('B00CZTCS9K', 1, 77, 96317, '2.25', 'http://www.amazon.com/Lemon-Recipes-Alkalizing-Addition-Delectable-ebook/dp/B00CZTCS9K%3FSubscriptionId%3DAKIAJPNAWJHXGB5IYXOA%26tag%3Dgenroad-21%26linkCode%3Dxm2%26camp%3D2025%26creative%3D165953%26creativeASIN%3DB00CZTCS9K')
```

Otherwise, mySQL will throw an error because it tries to parse the text as a column or mySQL construct.